# database schema designing difficulties

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2007, database-schema

[image]

Hello, i have database with the structure like that, and now i need to improve it, by making new tablet "contacts" and put in it phone numbers from tables "client" and "employees".
However i can't imagine how to do it, i tried similiar ways, but none of them give me correct answer.( it has to be one-to-many, like client or employee able to have a lot of numbers) Maybe someone of you can help me to make it? Am working with MS Access .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You leave out what other requirements you have.  Does it have to be a table or merely a table that combines the two temporarily?  Is it replacing your existing tables?

Create a union query between the two existing tables.  That's the fastest way for a universal contact list.  You may need to make a calculated field to create a unique index that can be combined in the union.

Good luck!

Comment: yes, it will storage phone numbers data from those two tables "client" and "employees", so in new database "client" table have only client_key, name, last_name, email, birth_day, address. Same goes with "employees" table. So the new table "contact" should have fields like ID and phone_number?